# docker-compose.yml file naming convention

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What is the naming convention for the `docker-compose.yml` file? Should it always be named like this or am I free to rename it to, for instance, `docker-compose-jenkins.yml`?

Comment: Why not just try renaming it?

Comment: I did not found a good answer online so I created this question to help other developers in the future. Is that so bad?

Comment: @Titulum In this case what you could do is just do it, see if it works, answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### default name:

Note that `docker-compose.yml` is the default name so if you want to use `docker-compose up` **without specifying a filename**, you will need to use that format. As mentioned, you can use multiple files as overrides (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)), by specifying one file *per* `-f` argument.

### Docker reference:

> The -f flag is optional. If you don’t provide this flag on the command
> line, Compose traverses the working directory and its parent
> directories looking for a docker-compose.yml and a
> docker-compose.override.yml file. You must supply at least the
> docker-compose.yml file. If both files are present on the same
> directory level, Compose combines the two files into a single
> configuration.
>
> The configuration in the docker-compose.override.yml file is applied
> over and in addition to the values in the docker-compose.yml file.

[[docs link]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)

Comment: Worth noting that it is now recommended to go with `compose.yml` first, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752628/1819160

Answer (score 16):

You can specify an alternate filename on the command line.

> -f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
>                                 (default: docker-compose.yml)

*Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/*

Given that the tool supports using any file name you'd like, you're free to name the file whatever you'd like. In fact, you can even specify **multiple** files at once.