# Why should you call the Docker Compose file 'compose.yaml' instead of 'docker-compose.yaml'?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've noticed that the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/03-compose-file/) now recommends calling Docker Compose's file `compose.yaml` instead of `docker-compose.yaml`.

Is there a reason for this change? Does the newer version provide more features?

Comment: Did my answer solved your doubts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this modification is quite old since it was made in 2021 and inserted in the [release `1.28.6`](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.6), one of the last versions before Docker Compose `V2`.

It was just a file renaming activity, with no new functionalities associated which, instead, follows the usual Docker Compose releases.

The main difference is that if you execute docker-compose with no options it will search for `compose.yml` first and then, if not present, for `docker-compose.yml` for backwards compatibility of earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to take a guess at it, it is due to that fact podman also has a compose and podman compose is a strict subset of docker compose. In other words, a podman compose file could be run by docker compose but a docker compose file will not always be runnable by a podman compose.

At least that's what I've gathered from this redhat link after a quick search on the difference between docker and podman compose.

[https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-compose-docker-compose#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20Podman%20Compose%20can,tested%2C%20and%20likely%20more%20stable](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-compose-docker-compose#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20Podman%20Compose%20can,tested%2C%20and%20likely%20more%20stable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the documentation I wasn't aware of podman